# Detect when Stop Debugging button is pressed in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, variables

I want to reset a variable when the stop debugging button is pressed so I'm just wondering, how would I go about detecting when it's pressed
Thanks

Comment: When you press stop, the program you are debugging is removed from memory.  Which variable are you going to reset?

Comment: It's used in a plugin. I have a button to attach a process, so I want to reset a boolean value. I want it so if something gets attached, a message box appears letting them know, and it lets them know if a process is already attached and also if there is nothing to attach.

However I want it so when the stop button is pressed, the user is notified that the process has been detached and then reset the "IsProcessAlreadyAttached" boolean to false

Comment: Ah, so this is a VS plugin then?

Comment: Yeah it is :)
Also, when I have my plugin working, how do I give it to people on another computer? What files do they need, where do they need to put them etc. I can't find anything about what to do when your plugin is finished

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an extension for VS, you can use IVsDebuggerEvents.OnModeChange which will tell you when the debugger has started/stopped/edit & continue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebuggerevents.onmodechange.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if it will work because my plugin attaches the w3wp process which is the debugger I think, and when I check if it's running with the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached, it always says its attached even when I haven't attached it. So I don't know if its a different debugger